# Primefaces layout component not finished on jQuery ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf-2, primefaces, facelets

I'm trying to layout my view with primefaces layout component, but when I use jQuery ready function the layout is still not created and I cant figure out the real size of my layout center. Does the layout component provides any event which I can catch in javascript? The resize event is not thrown.

Thanks,
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

Place your script after layout component.

Comment: What do you mean with after layout component? I'm using jQuery(function() { }); but seems like the primefaces layout component  uses also the onload method todo some stuff. If I use additional inside of the ready func an setTimeout with 100ms it works perfect.